# Backup and restore the whole system multiple times

Tags: backup, restore, oem

I am building a computer I am going to sell and need to make a restore system. I am running Ubuntu OEM install. What can I do so if it get restored multiple times. It still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're shipping identical systems and don't want to run the install multiple times, go ahead and run the OEM install, finish configuring it the way you want in preparation for the initial user boot, then image the drive.  For subsequent machines, instead of running the OEM install again, just write the image to the drive.

To do the image creation/restore, boot from a CD/USB drive in live mode.  You'd then do something like this:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/hard_drive_master.img sparse #create initial image file
dd of=/dev/sda if=/mnt/hard_drive_master.img sparse #Make each new hard drive
```